# Unable to connect to MAMP MySQL database using Wakanda's remote connection

Tags: mysql, wakanda

I'm trying to connect to a MAMP MySQL database from Wakanda 11.

I tried connecting to the localhost database using <kbd>Connect to Remote Datastore</kbd> but I keep getting a `Connection failed` response. I've also tried using port `127.0.0.1:8081` which it connects to but not when attempting to use `port:3306` which is where I have the MySQL database configured on the MAMP server. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried the following script...

```
model.addSQLCatalog("mysqldb", {
  hostname: '127.0.0.1', 
  port: 3306,
  user: 'root',
  password: 'xxxxxxxx',
  database: 'my_database_name',
  ssl: false,
  dbType: 'mysql'
});
```

...but this gives me the following error:

> TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.

How can I fix and make it work on port:3306 so I can see my database structures?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Wakanda Enterprise Edition 11 or higher there is a [MySQL Connector Pro](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/MySQL-Connector-Pro/Connecting-Wakanda-to-MySQL.200-1168886.en.html).

Here is an example of connecting with this:

```
model.mergeSQLCatalog(localName, {
    hostname: string 'host name',
    port: number remote_port_number,
    user: string 'userName', 
    password: string 'password',
    database: string 'SQL database name',
    jsFile: string 'configuration JavaScript file',
    ssl: boolean true or false,
    dbType: string 'mysql' } )
```

---

If you are on an older version of Wakanda Enterprise Edition but still using version 7 or higher then there is a [Wakanda/MySQL connector](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Wakanda-Enterprise-Edition/Connector-WakandaMySQL.200-1038041.en.html).

Here is an example of connecting to MySQL with the connector:

```
var sql = require('waf-sql');
    //use port 3306 and do not use SSL
var dbconn = sql.connect('mysql','192.168.0.21', 'john', 'x54?hsf5x!','arts',3306,false); 
var rs = dbconn.update("people", {
    name: "smith",
    age: 42
    }, {
        id: 1
    });
var rs = dbconn.select("*", "people", {
        id: 1
    });
var row = rs.getNextRow(); // get the first row
dbcon.close(); // close connection
```

Here is an example of the available parameters:

```
var params = {
    hostname: [your host name or IP address],
    user: [the user name of your DB],
    password: [the user password],
    database: [the DB name],
    port: [the port number of the MySQL Server, by default 3306],
    ssl: false,
    dbType : 'mysql'
};
```

Comment: I don't know where to locate the jsFile: string 'configuration JavaScript file'?

Comment: The docs say that is optional.  
"jsFile String (optional) Relative pathname of JavaScript configuration file located in the same folder as the model"

Comment: __ERROR:
message:
"Unexpected string, line #76, file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xxxxxxx_app/xxxxxx/_app/CyclingThroughModel.js."
componentSignature:
"jvsc"
errCode:
4055
message:
"Error evaluating javascript file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xxxxxx_app/xxxxxx_app/CyclingThroughModel.js"
componentSignature:
"JS4D"
errCode:
2

This was the error message returned was running model.mergeSQLCatalog script

Comment: what version of Wakanda are you using and what file are you placing this code in? I am a bit confused why the error message is referencing files inside of MAMP's hierarchy...

Comment: Currently using version 11 of Wakanda. I already use MAMP to access to MySQL via PhpMyAdmin. The MySQL port setting was changed to 3306. This works fine for me and I can see database created. The Wakanda setting.waSettings port is set to 8081. How do I configure the system to see see the data in the MySQL database, I'm a little confused what exactly to change to make work. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Are you using Wakanda **Enterprise** Edition? and is the call to `model.mergeSQLCatalog` is inside of **`model.js`**?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the following bit of script: 
    
    model.addSQLCatalog("mysqldb", {
    hostname: '127.0.0.1', 
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'xxxxxxxx',
    database: 'mydatabasename_db',
    ssl: false,
    dbType: 'mysql'
});

 and I received back this error message: 
"TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures."
Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Thanks :) Now working on Mac system, I have  tested with model.addSQLCatalog connection placed within the script file model.js:       

model.addSQLCatalog("mysqldb", {
    hostname: '127.0.0.1', 
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'xxxxxx',
    database: 'databasename_db',
    ssl: false,
    dbType: 'mysql'
});        

Ports were set to 80 and 3306 (mysql) respectively. My setting toe the settings.waSettings file were set to0: (Listening IP Address 127.0.0.1 and TCP Port 80)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct your issue has been solved? Does it work for both Windows & Mac ?

To resume , to use ProCOnnector you'll need :

- The Enterprise Version of Wakanda
- For the current v11 version of Wakanda, you need to use in the `model.js` file the `addSQLCatalog()` API.
- The parameters accepted are described in the doc

Please note in the next version of Wakanda we 'll provide to wizzard to connect to other DBs instead of the `addSQLCatalog()`. This will help and ease the process.

Comment: It seems when I installed MAMP there was conflict with the already installed  Apache2 server and MAMP Port assignment. Switching off MAMP has resolved the issue. My conclusion is to install MySQL, PHP and PHPMyAdmin separately via the terminal. I will be testing to check whether the issue is the same on a Windows solution platform with WAMP pre-installed.

Comment: OK great. Please keep us posted, to ensure that the issue is not Wakanda related. Thanks @Darrellh